# What am I missing in my CRC (Class Responsibility Collaborator) Model?

Tags: oop, single-responsibility-principle

I am trying to build a CRC model for an application intended to handle the power state of servers in a multicloud environment (Onprem, AWS, Azure) via schedules.

- A server may be assigned to **ONLY** one schedule at a time.
- The schedule simply goes by days for this iteration and does not go by date. So if you schedule a start and end time for monday it will be the same for every monday as an example.
- The user whom creates the schedule is the only one that should be able to modify that schedule.

I'm pretty sure this model is incomplete but I can't figure out what I need to add.

So far I have the following:

| **Class** | - |
| --- | --- |
| Server | - |
| Responsibilities | Collaborators |
| powerState | PowerScheduler |
| getPowerState() | - |
| setPowerState() | - |
| serverSchedule | - |
| getPowerSchedule | - |
| setPowerSchedule | - |

| **Class** | - |
| --- | --- |
| PowerScheduler | - |
| Responsibilities | Collaborators |
| Days | Day |

| **Class** | - |
| --- | --- |
| Day | - |
| Responsibilities | Collaborators |
| Start Time | PowerScheduler |
| End Time | - |